# Vue Api and Skeleton

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a beginner.

I should show a skeleton before the data is retrieved by the api. How could I do?

Thank you

My solution was to set a timeout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's done the work with promise:

```
mounted() {
  // Show the skeleton before fetching
  this.skeleton = true;
  axios.get('url')
  .then(response => 
  { 
    this.array = response.data; 
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // do something when error occurs
  })
  .finally(() => {
    // hide the skeleton in finally block is better than using setTimeout
    this.skeleton = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks and if I wanted to show the skeleton as a preview the timeout where should I insert it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please explain your idea more!

Comment: If the api are loading too fast, the skeleton won't show up right? I would like to show it even if the api load immediately .. In this case the timeout should I insert it in the axios request?

Comment: so you can use your setTimeout inside finally block if you want to achieve something like that: finally(() => {
   setTimeout(() => { this.skeleton = false; },3000) })
  });